# Using a batch file to copy last week's changes in the OneDrive folder and then compress

Tags: batch-file

I'm using xcopy and then 7z to copy and compress my whole Onedrive folder. Its very slow and wastes a lot of space by duplicating everything weekly.

I would like to scan the Onedrive folder for changes made in the week prior, and only copy and compress those.. is this possible?

This is what i have so far: (sorry im a bit of a noob!)

```
@ECHO OFF


Set currdate=%date:/=%


MD F:\ONEDRIVE_weekly_backups\OneDrive

xcopy /s /y /z /k /h /e "F:\OneDrive" "F:\ONEDRIVE_weekly_backups\OneDrive"


7z a -tzip "F:\ONEDRIVE_weekly_backups\ONEDRIVE_BACKUP_%currdate%.zip" "F:\ONEDRIVE_weekly_backups\\OneDrive*" -sdel -mx7
ECHO.

PAUSE
```

Comment: You should look at using the /M option with XCOPY.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51054/62576). Replace *delete* with *copy*. It should get you started. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9417913/62576) this robocopy version.